# Tasker/IFTTT - Dual SIM missed call auto sms respond

Tags: sms, tasker, automation, dual-sim, ifttt

Is it possible to create a script that send sms automatically when there is missed/declined call but send them based on which SIM the call was missed?  For example i miss a call that was going onto SIM 2 so it sends a sms from SIM 2 and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate) has dual SIM support, i.e. Subscription id in the [Call incoming](http://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/call_incoming.html) and [SMS send](http://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/sms_send.html) blocks.